# the aim is to plot at least 3 of my monthly variables across the 3 stations on a graph using ggplot. with the x axis showing the months

Tags: javascript, r, arrays, ggplot2, plot

This is a copy of what my data set looks like: parameter values gathered over 3 stations through  months May, June, July, Aug, Sep. I am trying to plot rainfall, air temp, water temp across the months for each station using ggplot. I keep getting error messages shown below.

How do I go about the code to plot these variables right. is it possible i'm not getting the column or row arrangement properly?

This is what i tried:

```
library(readxl)
badagry_stations <- read_excel("~/903 -/badagry stations.xlsx")
View(badagry_stations)
require(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2)
data.frame(badagry_stations)
tidyr::gather(badagry_stations)
summary(data.frame(badagry_stations))
ggplot(badagry_stations, aes(rainfall)) + geom_line(aes(air temperature)), colour = "red")
ggplot(dat, aes(rain, turbidity, colour = 'station'))
```

So i tried to rearrange the data sets as seen below like that could be the problem

```
   Station month Air.temperature Water.temperature...C. Rainfall..mm.
1  Station 1   MAY              31                  30.00         275.6
2  Station 1  JUNE              28                  28.67         236.2
3  Station 1  JULY              28                  29.00         142.7
4  Station 1   AUG              28                  27.00         257.6
5  Station 1  SEPT              28                  30.00         329.5
6  Station 2   MAY              29                  28.00         273.6
7  Station 2  JUNE              28                  28.67         236.2
8  Station 2  JULY              28                  29.00         142.7
9  Station 2   AUG              28                  27.00         257.6
10 Station 2  SEPT              28                  30.00         329.5
11 Station 3   MAY              30                  29.00         277.6
12 Station 3  JUNE              28                  28.67         236.2
13 Station 3  JULY              28                  29.00         142.7
14 Station 3   AUG              28                  27.00         257.6
15 Station 3  SEPT              28                  30.00         329.5
   Turbidity..NTU. TSS..mg.L. TDS..mg.L. pH...25.C Conductivity..µS.cm.
1             4.40          2    10199.0      7.22              18100.0
2             6.72          2    14701.0      7.29              24100.0
3             6.66         12     8618.0      7.35              13900.0
4             8.35          4    10450.1      7.34              16855.0
5            42.70         33     1712.0      7.34               2920.2
6             3.95          3     9873.0      7.76              15800.0
7             3.19          1    13620.0      7.45              22700.0
8            16.25         18     5144.1      7.45               8870.0
9            27.40         18     4912.6      7.61               8470.0
10           29.60         26     2482.7      7.31               4070.0
11            4.15          2     9964.0      7.16              16700.0
12            4.56          2    14100.0      7.48              23500.0
13           14.07         12     6182.0      7.44              10660.0
14           22.31         17     5063.4      7.63               8730.3
15           35.31         31     2696.2      7.32               4420.1
```

I also tried this data set rearrangement

```
data.frame(badagry_stations) 
                  month                 MAY.1                JUNE.1
    1                  Air temperature                    31                    28
    2           Water temperature (°C)                    30                 28.67
    3                    Rainfall (mm)    275.60000000000002                 236.2
```

but i keep getting this error code:

```
ggplot(badagry_stations, aes(rainfall)) + 
geom_line(aes(air temperature)), colour = "red")
        
#> Error: unexpected symbol in "ggplot(badagry_stations, aes(rainfall)) + 
#> geom_line(aes(air temperature"
```

Comment: When you have spaces in a variable name, you need to surround the variable name with backticks like this : `'air temperature'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to deal with multi-word column names is to use an underscore character to separate them.

Sample code:

```
#badagry_stations<-data.frame(badagry_stations) 
    #tidyr::gather(badagry_stations)
    #summary(data.frame(badagry_stations))
 

    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggthemes)
       
    ggplot(badagry_stations, aes(x=`Rainfall..mm.`,y=`Turbidity..NTU.`, group=Station)) + 
      geom_line(aes(color=Station), size=2)+
      theme_wsj()+
      labs(x="Rainfall(mm)", y="Turbidity(NTU)", fcolor="Station number" )+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
            strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=20, face="bold"),
            legend.text = element_text( color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
            legend.position="bottom",
            legend.box = "horizontal",
            legend.title = element_blank())
```

Plot:

[image]

Or group by `month` variable

Sample code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggthemes)

badagry_stations$month<-factor(badagry_stations$month,levels=c("MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUG","SEPT"))

ggplot(badagry_stations, aes(x=`Rainfall..mm.`,y=`Turbidity..NTU.`, group=month)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=month), stat="identity", width=1)+
  theme_wsj()+
  labs(x="Rainfall(mm)", y="Turbidity(NTU)", fcolor="Station number" )+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=20, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text( color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
badagry_stations<-structure(list(Station = c("Station 1", "Station 1", "Station 1", 
"Station 1", "Station 1", "Station 2", "Station 2", "Station 2", 
"Station 2", "Station 2", "Station 3", "Station 3", "Station 3", 
"Station 3", "Station 3"), month = c("MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUG", 
"SEPT", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUG", "SEPT", "MAY", "JUNE", 
"JULY", "AUG", "SEPT"), Air.temperature = c(31, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 30, 28, 28, 28, 28), Water.temperature = c(30, 
28.67, 29, 27, 30, 28, 28.67, 29, 27, 30, 29, 28.67, 29, 27, 
30), Rainfall..mm. = c(275.6, 236.2, 142.7, 257.6, 329.5, 273.6, 
236.2, 142.7, 257.6, 329.5, 277.6, 236.2, 142.7, 257.6, 329.5
), Turbidity..NTU. = c(4.4, 6.72, 6.66, 8.35, 42.7, 3.95, 3.19, 
16.25, 27.4, 29.6, 4.15, 4.56, 14.07, 22.31, 35.31), TSS..mg.L. = c(2L, 
2L, 12L, 4L, 33L, 3L, 1L, 18L, 18L, 26L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 17L, 31L
), TDS..mg.L. = c(10199, 14701, 8618, 10450.1, 1712, 9873, 13620, 
5144.1, 4912.6, 2482.7, 9964, 14100, 6182, 5063.4, 2696.2), pH...25.C = c(7.22, 
7.29, 7.35, 7.34, 7.34, 7.76, 7.45, 7.45, 7.61, 7.31, 7.16, 7.48, 
7.44, 7.63, 7.32), Conductivity..ÂµS.cm. = c(18100, 24100, 13900, 
16855, 2920, 15800, 22700, 8870, 8470, 4070, 16700, 23500, 10660, 
8730.3, 4420.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))
```